# Передача данных с помощью json

Tags: ajax, php, json

Приветствую всех.

```
    function getCount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.count);
            }
        });
    }
```

В index.php:

```
echo json_encode(array("count" => $count));
```

Ничего не выводит, не подскажите, в чем проблема?

Точнее, на странице выводится:

> {"count":1}{"count":2}{"count":3}{"count":4}{"count":5}{"count":6}{"count":7}{"count":8}{"count":9}{"count":10}{"count":11}{"count":12}{"count":13}{"count":14}{"count":15}

Comment: @evansive, покажите больше кода из index.php, расскажите, что вы пытаетесь получить?

Answer (score 2):

> echo json_encode(array("count" => $count));

Это у вас в цикле?, потому что вывод у вас будет для json некорректным

> {"count":1}{"count":2}{"count":3}{"count":4}{"count":5}{"count":6}{"count":7}{"count":8}{"count":9}{"count":10}{"count":11}{"count":12}{"count":13}{"count":14}{"count":15}

Я думаю он выводит то, что вы сказали, а вы сказали:

> Вывести массив ("count"=>$count) в формате JSON

---

> Необходимо, чтобы вывело просто значение переменной без всего этого.

сделайте тогда так:

```
echo $count;
```

---

Вот в этом методе вам помогут парсеры JSON-а

```
        success: function(data) {
            var z = JSON.parse(data); // например этот
            alert(z.count);
        }
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, да, нужно вывести массив в формате json, парсер не помог, то есть, success : function не выполняется, error : function выдает "undefined".

Comment: @evansive вот тут у вас не массив JSON, а набор JSON массивов

> {"count":1}{"count":2}{"count":3}{"count":4}{"count":5}{"count":6}{"count":7}{"count":8}{"count":9}{"count":10}{"count":11}{"count":12}{"count":13}{"count":14}{"count":15}

1) попробуйте убрать **dataType: "json",**

2) приведите в порядок вывод в php, чтобы выдавал либо один массив JSON, либо массив массивов в формате JSON. Для отладки в success делайте просто alert(data)

3) как отладите попробуйте распарсить data, либо с JSON.parse(data), либо можно найти аналог.

Comment: @IVsevolod, зачем отказываться от ``dataType: "json"`` и парсить вручную, когда ``jQuery`` это сделает сама, если параметр всё-таки указать?  
К слову, и для отладки лучше использовать ``console.log()``, если браузер позволяет.